# Could the energy emitted by galaxies contribute to the dark matter phenomenon?

Tags: cosmology, energy-conservation, mass-energy, dark-matter, galaxies

I'm pondering a concept regarding the energy-mass conversion in the context of cosmology, specifically related to the light emitted by galaxies over billions of years.

Einstein's famous equation E=mc^2 tells us that energy and mass are interchangeable. Over billions of years, galaxies emit a considerable amount of energy in the form of light. My question stems from considering this energy as mass.

Would it be feasible to consider that the mass of galaxies was significantly higher when they originally emitted the light we observe now? Could this "missing mass" be a contributor to the dark matter phenomenon that we can't yet fully explain?

Further, how would this perspective affect our understanding of the rotational dynamics of galaxies? For example, if we consider a galaxy X rotating as if its mass is Y, would the loss of energy (as light) significantly affect its rotational dynamics over billions of years?

I understand that the mass lost through light emission might be relatively small, but I'm interested in discussing this hypothesis and its potential implications for cosmology. Thank you in advance for your insights.

Answer (score 1):

Baryonic matter (the sort that can absorb or emit light) makes up only a few percent of the energy density of the universe and only about a fifth of the matter. This fraction is measured from estimates of the primordial abundances of helium and deuterium, created in the first 10 minutes or so of the universe's existence.

It seems to me unfeasible that these primordial baryons could somehow create 4 times their rest mass energy in the form of photons. The most efficient conversion processes in the universe - accretion onto black holes - appear to be no more than 10% efficient. Stars are less than 1% efficient at turning rest mass into light.

The mass/energy budget of the universe takes account of the radiation content of the universe. It is *small* at the present epoch and dominated by cosmic microwave background photons that outnumber baryons by a billion to one.

A big galaxy like the Milky Way has a luminosity to stellar mass ratio of about 1. i e. $10^{11}$ stars are emitting about $10^{11}$ solar luminosities of light. If we assume that has been going on for $10^{10}$ years, we can estimate that the Milky Way has lost just 0.07% of its baryonic rest mass energy in the form of light (i.e. negligible). Note also that the light escapes from the galaxy and plays no role in measurements of Galactic rotation now.